# difficult handled the dataset in jupiternotebook

Tags: pandas, dataset, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am working with a type of dataset which has multiple sheets and multiple column headers. In all property sheets, each cell has the sum of each relevant cell from the previous sheets. This data set has been collected from 1999 June to 2021 June.

Here is a screenshot of the dataset:

[image: 1]

And these are the row names of the data set. These are the same for every sheet in the dataset.

[image: 2]

I am a beginner at this kind of stuff. I tried many ways but was not able to make  dataset suitable for easy analysis in a suitable way. So, please help me to modify this dataset. I am using jupiter notebook.

These are questions that I should answer.
[image: 3]
From this, I think you can get a good idea about the analysis type that I try to perform.

Here are ways that I tried to set the header of the data set.
But the problem is all the rows have both **LGA** and **Region**. So I don't know how to handle this kind of data set.

Here I tried to get all the  data sheets into one data frame

```
import pandas as pd
df11=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\dataset.xlsx")
df11.columns = [c[0] + "_" + c[1] for c in df11.columns]
new_header = df11.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df11 = df11[1:] #take the data less the header row
df11.columns = new_header #set the
df11.head(20)
```

[image: 4]

Here I tried the multi-header option. But I don't know it is suitable]

```
df_dict = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Downloads\\dataset.xlsx", header=[0, 1,2], sheet_name=None)
df = pd.concat(df_dict.values(), axis=0)
df.head(20)
```

[image: 5]

Comment: Can you provide more information about the type of analysis you want to perform? Do you want to do a time series analysis? Currently your question is a bit too open ended and will probably be closed. Also when you say you "tried many ways" can you show us an example of what you tried? You'll be more likely to get responses if you showed you made a good faith effort. Thanks!

Comment: yes sure. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Can you attach your code as formatted text instead of screenshots? See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks? That way people wanting to help you can copy and paste it instead of having to type it out

Comment: I added code also. I am really sorry for mistake. This is my first time asking question in stack overflow

Comment: No worries. thanks for modifying your question, it looks a lot better!